# Searching keys in dictionary and answering the corresponding value

Tags: python

I have created a voice assistant with many functions. I want that I will create a dictionary and if I say anything then the assistant will search the  keys in the dictionary and if my sentence is found in the keys then the assistant will answer the corresponding value.

I have already created the assistant, is it possible to search in the dictionary for keys and answer the corresponding value?

Comment: `if key in dictionary: print(dictionary[key])`

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on Python. [so] is not a tutoring service.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all make a dictionary:

```
dict  = {'1':'one','2':two}
```

Then use the `get` method:

```
dict.get('1')
```

which will give output as:

```
one
```

The use of `.get` returns the corresponding value of key.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable. It is a keyword in python

Comment: Thank you very very much